# Regarding convergence of improper integral to be used in Analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, improper-integrals, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying Tom M Apostol Introduction to Analytic number theory.

> In theorem 4.12 Apostol uses  that improper integral $\int_x^{\infty} \frac {1} { t (logt) ^2  } \ , dt $ converges, x>2 .

I tried using comparison test by comparing with $t^{3/2} $ and $ t^2 $ but I don't get non-zero finite limit of there ratios as t tends to $\infty $ .

Can someone please tell how to prove this integral to be convergent  .

Comment: Hint: The integrand is exactly the derivative of$$-\frac1{\log{(t)}}$$which can be seen by substituting $u=\log{(t)}$. So the given integral converges to $$\frac1{\log{(x)}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand has a simple antiderivative:

$$\int_x^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t (\log{t})^2} = \left [ -\frac1{\log{t}} \right ]_x^{\infty} = \frac1{\log{x}}$$

Note that the integral converges because $\log{t} \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.